# can i create a cron job with no scheduling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I want to set a cron job that will be with run only by app-engine ui triggering (pressing a button on app-engine)

How can i set the cron.xml to include no scheduling?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/match</url>
        <description>find buddies to all users</description>
        <schedule>----?-----</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible.

I see 2 possible alternatives, based on a flag controlled by the GUI, indicating if the "cron" job should run or not:

- have a regular cron just check if the flag is set: do the job if it is set and exit immediately if it's not

or,

- use [the deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en): when setting the flag also trigger a deferred task, which, in addition to executing the job also keeps triggering itself as long as the flag is set; the deferred library also allows repeating the task at sub-second intervals, which is not possible with regular cron (if that's of interest to you).

**Update:**

The deferred library has at least one drawback: can't access the request handler inside the deferred function. But the deferred functionality is also available in the [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) (mentioned by @jirungaray's answer) - using the optional `countdown` or `eta` arguments to [taskqueue.add()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue):

> - countdown -- Time in seconds into the future that this task should run or be leased. Defaults to zero. Do not specify this argument if
>     you specified an eta.
> - eta -- A `datetime.datetime` that specifies the absolute earliest time at which the task should run. You cannot specify this argument if
>     the countdown argument is specified. This argument can be time
>     zone-aware or time zone-naive, or set to a time in the past. If the
>     argument is set to None, the default value is now. For pull tasks, no
>     worker can lease the task before the time indicated by the eta
>     argument.

This makes task queues preferable to the deferred library.

Comment: i need it to case when i want to stop (freeze) the cron for a long time. Say It's a debug app and I want to stop the cron.

Answer (score 1):

Seems what your really need is [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/), which are tasks designed to be processed off the main request thread.They work on background instances so they are assigned the same restrictions as cron executions (10 min limit, etc).

Debugging a PaaS is always messy, Google integrated the [Stackdriver debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/) but I'm not really clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

A cron job simply calls your handler at a given time. If you don't want scheduling, just type in your handler in the browser window and press enter, e.g.:

```
https://my-app.appspot.com/generate_report
```

The result is the same as pressing "Run now" button in the console.

If you want, you can also protect this handler with some token that your code will check before executing it.

Comment: i need it to case when i want to stop (freeze) the cron for a long time. Say It's a debug app and I want to stop the cron.

Comment: Cron jobs run for a few milliseconds. You are talking about a task that a cron job starts, but this is totally different. There is already a tool to stop a task which runs in a queue through the console.

Comment: Note that you can also pause a queue. So you can put your tasks to a separate queue, and then pause/restart it as necessary.